# In Office 365, How to get an Excel array function to spill and render properly in the worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

With Excel 2019 and Office 365, MS introduced changes to array functions such that they are at least a bit less rigid.

Suppose I have the following VBA function

```
Public Function fooo(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Variant
    Dim mat() As Integer
    ReDim mat(0 To a - 1, 0 To b - 1) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 0 To a - 1
        For j = 0 To b - 1
            mat(i, j) = a
        Next j
    Next i
    fooo = mat
End Function
```

and go into a sheet and type `=fooo(4,4)` into a cell.  All I have to do is press enter, not control-shift-enter, and Excel executes my array function, leaving me an 4 x 4 array of 4s.  So far so good.

Now if I try the following from VBA

```
Public Sub tryit()
    Range("a40").FormulaArray = "=fooo(3,10)"
    Range("a40").Calculate
End Sub
```

I see a 3 in cell a40, but not the rest of the matrix.  Only when I click on the cell and press enter does the rest of the matrix appear.

Moving right along, I can now try something like this

```
Public Sub tryit2()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        Range("a40").FormulaArray = "=fooo(" & (i + 3) & "," & (i + 3) & ")"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Next i
End Sub
```

If cell a40 contains the matrix from before, this code happily overwrites the matrix there already.  Yeah, sure, there are some #N/As, but I can live with that.  But if that cell was previously fresh, Excel only shows that first number.

It almost looks like Excel pre-allocates a block of cells for the result, just not with VBA.

How can I get that initial array function to display from VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `tryit`, use `Formula2` instead of `FormulaArray`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2):

> Formulas set using `Range.Formula2` will always be evaluated as an array and may spill if more than 1 result is returned.